# Как мне сделать один в одном атрибуте разный цвет букв?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind

У меня есть задача сделать один текст одного цвета а другой другого. Я не пойму как мне реализовать эту задачу. Если я делю сразу на несколько атрибутов, то не могу понять как позиционировать элементы как на макете.  Использую tailwind. Вот макет, как нужно чтобы было:
[image: Как нужно]

Вот мой примерный код, без понятия позиционирования элементов как нужно.

```
   <div class="line">
  <hr class="mt-10 .border border-gray-400" />
  <div class="line-text flex mt-9">
    <h3 class="text-white">Copyright © 2021</h3>
    <h3 class="text-white  ">Design by</h3>
    <h3 class="text-green-500 ">Alibek Sergeev</h3>
  </div>
  <hr class="mt-10 .border border-gray-400" />
</div>
```

[image: Как сейчас у меня]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заключаете каждую букву в отдельный тег и редактируете стиль для каждого тега. Вот пример.

```
<h1 style = "color:red" >п<dev style = "color:green">р</dev><dev style = "color:black">и</dev><dev style = "color:blue">в</dev><dev style = "color:pink">е</dev><dev style = "color:green">т</dev></h1>
```

[image: картинка]

Answer (score 1):

На само деле такое себе решение. Лучше поставить каждую букву в span

```css
.aboba{
  text-colot: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="aboba">А</span>
```

а дальше просто применить цвета